# How to round off timestamp in milliseconds to nearest seconds?

Tags: java, c++, timestamp, milliseconds, seconds

How to round off the current timestamp in milliseconds to seconds?

If this is the current timestamp in milliseconds I have -

```
1384393612958
```

The if I am rounding off to nearest second then will it be like this?

```
Time in MS rounded off to nearest Second = 1384393612000
```

I might need to do this both in Java and C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Python:

```
old_number = 1384393612958
new_number = 1000 * (old_number / 1000)

print new_number
```

Basically you want to use an integer number, divide by one thousand (to shave off the milli-seconds), and then multiple by thousand to get the ms value rounded to seconds.

Comment: Technically, that's truncating the number to the previous second, not rounding to nearest, which would be more like `1000 * ((old_number + 500) / 1000)`...

Comment: @twalberg, While true, TrekkieTechie's example truncates the number.

Comment: @BrianS Hmmm... I hadn't noticed that, but you're right... So it seems OP isn't sure whether they want rounding or truncation.

Comment: In Python you can obtain it rounded from the beginning: int(round(time.time()))

Comment: For Python 3, replace `/` with `//`

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use Calendar to something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(millisec);
int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECONDS);
```

Alternatively (and can work for C++ too) you can do:

```
int sec = ((millisec + 500) / 1000);
```

adding 500 ms allows you to round the number properly.

Comment: FYI, this code uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_384_393_612_958L ) 
       .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )
       .toEpochMilli()
```

## java.time

The modern approach in Java uses the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_384_393_612_958L ) ;
Instant instantTrunc = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
long millis = instantTrunc.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is needed to convert java date object to mysql datetime formatted string in sql queries.
```

Conversion:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(this.id.getCreatedOn());
if (cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) >= 500 ) {
  System.out.println("Round off milliseconds to seconds");
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 1);
}
Date roundedCreatedOn = cal.getTime();
```

Actual query string contains:

createdOn = '" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(roundedCreatedOn)+ "'"

Comment: without this, mysql's timestamp column did not match the query generated using  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(roundedCreatedOn)   as SimpleDateFormat just drops additional milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, using the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
moment(timestamp).startOf('second')
```